# RabbitMQ Sample not working in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, rabbitmq

I'm trying to use rabbitMQ under a WPF application.I've followed the sample that are present on rabbitmq site.

The sender is a console application that does

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost" };


        using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
        {

                using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
                {
                    channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "hello",
                        durable: false,
                        exclusive: false,
                        autoDelete: false,
                        arguments: null);

                    string message = "Hello World!";
                    var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

                    channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "",
                        routingKey: "hello",
                        basicProperties: null,
                        body: body);
                    Console.WriteLine(" [x] Sent {0}", message);
                }
            }

    }
```

The MainWindowViewModel does

```
 public class MainWindowViewModel :ViewModelBase
{
    protected override Task InitializeAsync()
    {
        var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost" };
        using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
        using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
        {
            channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "hello", durable: false, exclusive: false, autoDelete: false, arguments: null);

            var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
            consumer.Registered += Consumer_Registered;
            consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
            {
                var body = ea.Body;
                var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
                Console.WriteLine(" [x] Received {0}", message);
            };
            channel.BasicConsume(queue: "hello", autoAck: true, consumer: consumer);

        }

        return base.InitializeAsync();
    }

    private void Consumer_Registered(object sender, ConsumerEventArgs e)
    {
        int t = 0;
    }
}
```

This code doesn't work on wpf. the same put in a console application works

I've noticed that the Consumer_Registered is fired... anyone has got a similar issue? As far I've  seen the channel creation is ok

Thanks

Comment: It's a base method from Catel MVVM  framework... I don't get the Received event fired

Comment: Question about this setup in console application mode: what prevents the console application from exitting? For me it seems that the setup is being destroyed after exitting this function.

Comment: I've seen right now that my problem is with the wpf part that exits the using statement... so I've to use a raisevent or something like that to keep it alive

Comment: As alternative; you can implement `IDispose` on your viewmodel and perform destruction there.

Answer (score 0):

The connection and the channel dispose when function `InitializeAsync` is finished. You should keep them alive. One option is to add them as properties, and assign them in `InitializeAsync`.